# How to move individual cells in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

Would anyone happen to know of a quick way to move the contents of one cell into another in Google Sheets. All of the cells will remain static, so I don't have to worry about additional rows or columns being added to my sheet.

I have tried to getCell(), just like the getLastColumn() function, but getCell() doesn't seem to be a valid function.

Code that I currently have:

```
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var s = event.source.getActiveSheet();
var r = event.source.getActiveRange();    
if(s.getName() == "Sheet4" && r.getColumn() == 15 && r.getValue() == "GO" ) {
    var row = r.getRow();
    var numColumns = s.getLastColumn();
    var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
    ss.getSheets()[1].getRange("A48:A48").copyTo(ss.getSheets()[2].getRange("A3:A3"),{contentsOnly:true});
```

Comment: To the same sheet ? other sheet in the same spreadsheet ? other spreadsheet ?

Comment: To the same sheet. I have added some sample code that i've pieced together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
function CopyTo() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet4');
var s = ss.getRange('H48');
s.copyTo(ss.getRange('D13'), {contentsOnly: true});
s.clear (); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Var source = ss.getRange ("Sheet4!H48:H48");      
  var targetSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet4");
  var targetRange = targetSheet.getRange("D13:D13"); 
  source.copyTo(targetRange, {contentsOnly: true});  
  source.clear ();
```